# Disable GUI ActiveX Shell.Explorer script error messages

Tags: browser, activex, message

While you browse in a gui's activex control shell.explorer, sometimes the page has an script error and a message appears saying there was an error and stopping the program. How can I block these messages from the activex? I know I can in IE, in the settings menu or somewhere and I did it but it doesn't apply for activex control as it runs separately from IE (if you login somewhere in IE you also have to login on the activex, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found out what I wanted. I wanted to turn off the annoying script error messages and you can do so with IEObj.silent:=1